# Парсинг значения аргумента aria-label

Tags: python

Кода пока нет, но я хотел бы узнать есть ли какой либо способ парсить значение аргумента aria-label?

Comment: можете скинуть сайт,где есть этот aria-label,может найду способ

Comment: https://hd.kinopoisk.ru/selection/4e1f289b03b8f49f8530bc56839e9085?selectionWindowId=tvod_est

Comment: да, вы совершенно правы!

Comment: не,у меня идей нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

src_url = "https://hd.kinopoisk.ru/selection/4e1f289b03b8f49f8530bc56839e9085?selectionWindowId=tvod_est"

target_url = "https://api.ott.kinopoisk.ru/v10/selections/{}".format(
    src_url.split("?", 1)[0].split("/")[-1]
)

resp = requests.get(
    url=target_url,
    headers={
        "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
    },
    params={
        "limit": 40,
        "offset": 0,
        "selectionWindowId": "tvod_est",
        "serviceId": 25
    }
).json()

for item in resp["data"]:
    print("{} {}, {}".format(item["title"], item["years"], item["genres"][0]))
```

Comment: а можете подсказать как парсить еще и цену?

Comment: @kiber Смотрите содержимое `resp`. Порицаю тупое копирование кода.

Comment: нет вот смотрите в последней строчке item["resp"] писать?